# How to keep a button highlited (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I have 7 `<input type="button"/>`s for switching between 7 views (different datasets). 
Now I want to highlight that button, that is clicked, and which view is shown. Example below:

[image: Example]

```
const [view,setView]=useState()

<input type="button" onClick={()=>{setView("view1")}} value="View1"/>
<input type="button" onClick={()=>{setView("view2")}} value="View2"/>
<input type="button" onClick={()=>{setView("view3")}} value="View3"/>
...

// for showing the corresponding view
{view==="view1"&& //show view1}
{view==="view2"&& //show view2}
...
```

I did this with the `:focus` property in CSS but when I click somewhere else, the focus obviously isn't on the button anymore, while the view still is shown. 
Are there any suggestions on how to keep the button highlited, as long as the view is shown?

Comment: Please provide your code, so that community could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it very easy.
I added an inline styling to each button depending on the active view of my "state":

```
<input type="button" style={{backgroundColor:(view=="view1")?"purple":"grey"}} onClick={()=>{setView("view1")}} value="View1"/>
<input type="button" style={{backgroundColor:(view=="view2")?"purple":"grey"}} onClick={()=>{setView("view2")}} value="View2"/>
<input type="button" style={{backgroundColor:(view=="view3")?"purple":"grey"}} onClick={()=>{setView("view3")}} value="View3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "view" variable has the information you need to do this. Each of your view buttons can check to see if they are active, and if they are give themselves the active class.

```js
<input
  type="button"
  onClick={/** Your callback */}
  className={view === "view1" ? "active" : null}
  value="View1"
/>
```

Then instead of using :focus, your css can use .active. :focus has a [narrow and well defined scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus). Trying to extend that use will probably only lead to difficult to read code and browser incompatibilites.

Also, and incidentally, you could use a loop to build your buttons like the following.

```js
const buttons = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  const viewId = `view${i}`;
  buttons.push(<input
    key={i}
    type="button" 
    onClick={()=>{setView(viewId)}
    className={viewId === view ? "active" : null}
    value=`View${i}`
  />);
}
```

Then use {buttons} in your return.